# How to use unicode in perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

Is it possible to get the correct output from this script?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = "wo3";
$str =~ s/wo3/wǒ/g;
print("'$str'\n");
```

I expect to see 'wǒ', not 'wo'

Comment: That script does output `'wǒ'`. It's a two-wrongs happen to make a right kind of situation that's remedied by the changes mentioned by Shawn

Answer (score 3):

If you have UTF-8 text directly in a perl script, you need to tell perl that with the [`utf8` pragma](https://perldoc.pl/utf8):

```
use utf8;
use open qw/:std :encoding(UTF-8)/; # Tell perl that STDOUT etc. should be UTF-8 encoded
use strict;
use warnings;
my $str = "wo3";
$str =~ s/wo3/wǒ/g;
print("'$str'\n");
```

Running it:

```
$ perl foo.pl
'wǒ'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use modules to save yourself tedious work.

```
› perl -mCEDict::Pinyin -E'
    say CEDict::Pinyin->new("wo3")->diacritic
'
wǒ

› perl -Mutf8 -mLingua::Han::PinYin -E'
    say Lingua::Han::PinYin
        ->new(unicode => 1)
        ->han2pinyin("我")
'
wǒ
```

[CEDict::Pinyin](http://p3rl.org/CEDict::Pinyin), [Lingua::Han::PinYin](http://p3rl.org/Lingua::Han::PinYin)

Comment: ug, Both modules produce UTF-8 rather than decoded text :( Worse, Lingua::Han::PinYin suffers from The Unicode Bug (as you can tell by removing `-Mutf8`).